# go through sub directories using for loop in batch

Tags: spring-batch

I try make a script witch go through a directory and for each file in the directory it will make a zip archive copy the archive somewhere else and then extract the archive. In the end, the whole directory i copy from has to equal to the new directory somewhere else but in files were copied has archive.
i had a problem with going through all files in the directory because it has a lot of sub directories so i could not go through all of them with a simple for loop.
My plan was to copy first all the directories and sub directories "xcopy /t /e" and then go through the files and archive copy and extract each one of them individually but as i said earlier i could not do it.
If someone can help me and show me how to to go through files like that or how to accomplish my mission, it will be perfect.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion for that. Both zip -r or rsync could do the job in a very simple way. You do not have to loop.